# Question About the Discrete Topology

Tags: general-topology

Since we define the discrete topology of a set $X$ as the set of all possible subsets of $X$, we are forced to consider individual elements of $X$ as open sets.

My question then is, do we consider individual elements as members of the discrete topology or do we have to consider the sets which only contain a single element as members of the discrete topology?

For example, in the discrete topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$, is the point $(1,1)$ a member of the topology, or would we have to say that the set $\{(1,1)\}$ is a member of the topology?

Not sure if this matters, but the way I understand it, is that for subsets we require more than one element, otherwise it is just a member of the set if that makes sense.

Comment: a topology is a collection of subsets...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A singleton is also a subset. For any $x \in X, \{x\}$ is a subset of $X$ and hence belongs to the discrete topology.

If $\tau$ is the discrete topology on $X,$ then $\{x\}\in \tau$ but $x \notin \tau.$

Answer (score 2):

It is not the individual elements that are open sets, but rather the subsets with just one element; there is a real difference betwen $x$ and $\{x\}$. Thus, the point $\langle 1,1\rangle$ is not a member of the discrete topology on $\Bbb R^2$ and so is not an open set in that space, but the singleton set $\{\langle 1,1\rangle\}$ **is** a member of the topology. A set can have any number of elements, including none at all; indeed, the empty set, which has no elements, is by definition an open set in **every** topological space.

Answer (score 2):

You say "the way I understand it is that for subsets we require more than one element, otherwise it is just a member of the set, if that makes sense." That makes sense but it's wrong. A subset of $X$ with just one element is definitely **not** an element of $X$.